# xElement Linq Creating List

Tags: c#, xml, class, xelement

I have created new class to read the data from xml file, which looks like :

```
public class Validations
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public List<string> lhsList { get; set; }
  public List<string> rhsList { get; set; }
}
```

`XML` I am trying to read is:

```
<root>
<Validation id="val3">
    <lhs id='Estimated' />
    <lhs id='Newqurter' />
    <rhs id='Current' />
    <rhs id='FirstQuarter' />
</Validation>
.
.
.

</root>
```

Code I have written to read the xml is :

```
List<Validations> vList = new List<Validations>();
vList = (from XElement xele in xdoc.Root.Elements()
  select new Validations
  { 
    id = xele.Attribute("id").Value.ToString(),
    // lhsList = ((xele.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "lhs").FirstAttribute.Value
    // rhsList = ((xele.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "rhs").FirstAttribute.Value
  }
).ToList<Validations>();
```

How do read the `List<lhsList>` ?
I tried

```
lhsList = ((xele.Elements().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "lhs").FirstAttribute.Value).ToList(),
```

But its not working as expected. What can be other ways to do this?

Comment: "Is not working" is a *very poor* problem description.

Comment: shouldn't this line  }).ToList<Validations>(); be something like this  }).ToList();

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: otherwise you would have to go ToString().ToList() but can't really tell by the description

Comment: @DJ Kraze: Iam not getting that option after `ToString()`

Comment: You have a List<Validations> vList so it's return type is expecting a List<> not a string so have to tried {).ToList(); you need to Iterate the vList you need a foreach statement..also the "," after Value.ToString,

Comment: U R Right. Kraze...`}).ToList<Validations>()` wasn't needed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the list of `lhs` elements as follows:

```
List<string> lhsElements = xele.Elements("lhs")
                               .Select(el => el.Attribute("id").Value)
                               .ToList();
```

This selects all the `lhs` elements that are children of `xele`, then selects the value of their 'id' attribute. I'll leave it to you to work out how to merge this with your code.

Comment: It worked.Thanks. I will always remember this method . there are so much to learn about xml. wow. :-)

Comment: sure ... just place this code inside your Validations initialisation block.